# Issue AppSync mutation from Step Function?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-appsync, aws-step-functions

Is it possible to issue an AppSync mutation directly from a Step Function? Looking to avoid creating a Lambda function for this one task. I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need a Lambda Task, unless the GraphQL service is exposed via a API Gateway endpoint.

*"Issue an AppSync mutation"* means *"make a HTTP POST request"*, of course.  Alas, there is no native Step Functions support to make arbitrary POST requests.  Step Functions does have an optimised integration with [ApiGateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-api-gateway.html) to make authorised POST requests with custom headers only to API Gateway endpoints.